# Making a lauched QT applicatioin get Focus in windows

Tags: c++, qt

Currently whenever my application starts it does not appear in the foreground. It appears on the taskbar but it does not get focus. I tried doing the following

```
application.setActiveWindow(&w);//w if my form widget
```

but this just makes it blink. Any suggestion on how I could set the focus to my application.

Comment: IIRC, Windows doesn't allow you to raise the application to foreground unless the application in the foreground allows you to. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: does window->setFocus(Qt::ActiveWindowFocusReason); works?